# Code in both if and else running

Tags: php, oop

I have no idea how this is happening and have never seen it happen before.

In the code below, the code prints out 'oops --- ' yet it runs the function somehow. I dont get how both the if and the else run, genuinely confused. I can provide the code in the classes if needed.

```
if($functions->checkDBstats($_GET['name'])) {
        $functions->update($_GET['name'],$functions->getPlayerInfo($_GET['name']));
        echo "Your account has been updated! Visit your page <a href='/osrstracker/name/". $_GET['name'] ."'>here</a>";
    } else {
        echo "Oops, either you havess already updated your account within the past 12 hours or we have messed something up!";
    }
```

Another thing I tested was adding a `print_r` to the `$functions->update` to debug it yet it doesnt print but the update function runs!! I have no idea whats going on =/ Anyone that can help ?

Comment: Is it running `$functions->update($_GET['name'],$functions->getPlayerInfo($_GET['name']));` ?

Comment: it updates and echoes 'oops' ?

Comment: It doesnt run the echo 'Your account has been updated' but it updates ( running `$functions->update($_GET['name'],$functions->getPlayerInfo($_GET['name']));`

Comment: @Batzz: It is possible only if you are running if else through loop. If your loop is running two times then it is possible that first time it execute if statement and second time execute else statement and you think both are executed simultaneously.

Comment: There is no loop around the if / else, and even if it was true then the 'Your account has been updated!' would have been printed which it hasnt.

Comment: How do you check that $functions->update() was executed? What is $functions->checkDBstats() doing? Give us more code :)

Comment: I know the code was executed as data in the database is populated - sorry for the late reply.